# What Spock, Geb and Selenium versions should be used with Grails 2.2?

Tags: grails, selenium, spock, geb

Has anyone managed to get the Geb and Spock plugins working with Grails 2.2?

If so, what exact versions of Geb, Selenium and Spock are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [pull request](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-grails/pull/7) in the Grails Geb example that updates to 2.2

The version can be found in the "files changed" tab:

```
def gebVersion = '0.9.0-RC-1'
def seleniumVersion = '2.27.0'
def spockVersion = '0.7'
```

Comment: Yes, 2.28 is compatible with Firefox version 18.

Answer (score 0):

My config that works on 2.2.3

in grails-app/Config/BuildConfig.groovy

```
def gebVersion = '0.9.0'
def seleniumVersion = '2.21.0'
def spockVersion = '0.7

dependencies {

    test("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:$seleniumVersion") {
        exclude "xml-apis"
        }       
    test("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion")
    test("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion")        

    test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"
    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    }

 plugins {
        test    ":spock:$spockVersion"
        test    ":geb:$gebVersion"
        }
```

In test/functional/GebConfig.groovy

```
/*
 This is the Geb configuration file.
 See: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/configuration.html
 */

import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

// Use htmlunit as the default
// See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver
driver = {
    def driver = new HtmlUnitDriver()
    driver.javascriptEnabled = true
    driver
}

environments {

    // run as “grails -Dgeb.env=chrome test-app”
    // See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver
    chrome {
        driver = { new ChromeDriver() }
    }

    // run as “grails -Dgeb.env=firefox test-app”
    // See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver
    firefox {
        driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }
    }

}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the reply. Selenium 2.28.0 also works on 2.2.3.

Comment: I'm using latest.release